# c++ really confusing linking error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, header-files

i keep getting these errors:

`cNeuralNetv2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Matrix::set(int,int,double)" (?set@Matrix@@QAEXHHN@Z) referenced in function _wmain`

and

`cNeuralNetv2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Matrix::toStr(void)" (?toStr@Matrix@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function _wmain`

my header file looks like this:

```
class Matrix{
    private:
        double** mat;
        void makeInitArray();

   public:
       int height, width;
       double at(int, int);
       void set(int, int, double);
       void add(int, int, double);
       string dimensions();
       string toStr();
       Matrix(int h, int w);
};
Matrix dotMatrices(Matrix a, Matrix b);
```

and my matrix.cpp file looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class Matrix{
private:
    double** mat;

    void makeInitArray(){
        mat = 0;
        mat = new double*[height];
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        {
            mat[h] = new double[width];
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
            {
                // fill in some initial values
                mat[h][w] = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }

public:
    int height, width;

    double at(int x, int y){
        return mat[x][y];
    }

    void set(int x, int y, double z){
        mat[x][y] = z;
    }

    void add(int x, int y, double z){
        mat[x][y] = z;
    }

    string toStr(){
        string output = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < height; x++){
            output += "[ ";
            for (int y = 0; y < width; y++){
                output += to_string(mat[x][y]);
                output += " ";
            }
            output += "]\n";
        }
        return output;
    }

    string dimensions(){
        return to_string(height) + "x" + to_string(width);
    }

    Matrix(int h, int w){
        height = h;
        width = w;
        makeInitArray();
    }
};
```

my main file looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

#include "mat.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Matrix nMat(4, 3);
    cout << nMat.toStr() << endl;
    cout << nMat.dimensions() << endl;
    nMat.add(0, 0, 1);
    nMat.at(0, 0);
    nMat.set(0, 0, 2);
    int q;
    cin >> q;
    return 0;
}
```

i'm a noob at c++, but i've been looking at this for 4 days, asking friends and no one seems to have an answer

Comment: have you included `string` in header file?

Comment: Your matrix.cpp file is wrong, it declares another different class called `Matrix`, which is undefined behaviour (violates ODR).

Comment: You don't declare the class in both the header and source file. You use the `Matrix::` syntax in the cpp to write the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined the Matrix class twice - once in the header and once in the .cpp file.  You want the class definition in the header, and the member function definitions in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

1- include class string in Matrix class header as long as you declare some members of type class string.

2- make the header `class Matrix` only has the interface and in Matrix source file only definition not declaring again class Matrix.

your `Matrix.h` will look like:

```
#include <string> // don't forget

class Matrix
{
    private:
        double** mat;
        int height, width; // declare member data private or protected an provide setters and getters instead of declaring them public
        void makeInitArray();

   public:          
       void add(int, int, double);
       // ...
};
```

and Matrix source `Matrix.cpp` will look like:

```
#include "matrix.h"
// some other include headers here...

void Matrix::makeInitArray() // don't write: void makeInitArray() directly
{
    mat = 0;
    mat = new double*[height];
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        mat[h] = new double[width];
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            // fill in some initial values
            mat[h][w] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}

double Matrix::at(int x, int y)
{
    return mat[x][y];
}
```

continue with the other member functions' definitions like above.

Comment: look for std::to_string(). It is defined in string header file. It is kind of alias of std::stoi or atoi